# How to know what ActionBar.Tab is being created

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, fragment

I put the same Fragment class inside five Tabs (the tabs are created in ActionBar). Theirs behaviors are similar but I need to know what Tab is being created in background because I will make the different request for DB. I don't need to know what tab is active.
I realized that Dalvik Virtual Machine creates only 2 tabs each time even though has five.
for example: I click on Tab2, the system does the code for Tab3 but it doesn't show it and  destroys Tab1.
My problem is detect what tab is being created in background.

Thanks

Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

You Can Write A Log File for each Tab Hence you can easily find it out my friend .

You can easily seen all the process of that tab execution inside the logcat.